# Clipping images to a rounded rectangle with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

How can I use ImageMagick to convert an image like [this](https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/c/8/c893bbb7-0589-4544-a488-f84f9aa1d058.jpg) to a PNG with a rounded rectangle on a transparent background?

Not all images in the set have clean borders, so I prefer to work with a standardized mask instead of something like `-trim`. I want to do the ImageMagick equivalent of CSS' `border-radius: 4.75% / 3.5%` to apply a mask to the card and save the result as a PNG containing a rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hours of digging through ImageMagick's documentation later, I found the trick.

First, make a rounded rectangle that will serve as a mask.

```
convert -size 672x936 xc:black -fill white -draw "roundRectangle 0,0,672,936 32,33" generatedcardmask.png
```

If you care about the details of how this works, read up on [the overall commandline structure of ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php), [creating masks](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/) and [drawing shapes](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#draw).

For the rounded rectangle's corner widths and heights, I calculated them as follows:

- Width: 672px *  4.75% = 31.92px (rounded to 32px)
- Height: 936px * 3.5% = 32.76px (rounded to 33px)

This generates the following PNG:

[image: generated image]

Then I can take the original image and use this mask PNG to replace the alpha values:

```
convert tsp-156-fortune-thief.jpg generatedcardmask.png -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite -colorspace RGB test.png
```

I cannot post the result here for copyright reasons, but feel free to try it out based on [this image](https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/c/8/c893bbb7-0589-4544-a488-f84f9aa1d058.jpg).